# Location of PHP class

Tags: php, path, include

A PHP newbie question. I am trying to make my first web page using a php class for navigation and some php for including html files - trying to be efficient. It all works fine at the top of the directory structure but I don't know how to make it work in all the sub-folders.

The (linux) server is a fileshare and I have access to a root folder with a www folder for serving web pages.

I have trawled this site and the web but I am completely confused about how to specify the path to the php and class files to be included in each page.

I know this is really basic php but I am really old (well, almost 60) and learning is getting harder.

Comment: Create a variable which holds the base/root path for all files to use.  Includes can be relative to that variable.

Comment: You might want to checkout this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQkfAdZbAJE&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=6 and skip to 5:00 thats a very usefull method to include a class in your system

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it is as suggested by Jeremy Miller in the comment, by use of a variable indicating your root folder (absolute path), and referring to it each time. Otherwise, you should know that `"../path"` notation indicates the parent folder in PHP, and you can use it multiple times to traverse up the tree: `"../../path"` and so on.